# reload existing UITableViewCell with different height and content

Tags: iphone, uitableview

To reload cell height and content I have called:

```
[[self tableView]reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:kSectionShoppingList]] withRowAnimation:UITab
```

This function calls the HeightForRow Data Source method, but it does not call CellForRowAtIndexPath data source method.

Is it their default behavior or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Try reloadSectionAtIndexPath method.

**UPDATE**

You need to calculate height before you display cell. Like in heightForRowAtIndexPath.

Use this method to display variable height rows.

Comment: i dont want to reload full section.

Comment: @False Alarm - in CellForRowAtIndexPath if i dont set focus from textField it work normally as expected . strange behaviour.:)

Comment: Height is set on basic of condition in heightForRowAtIndexPath..... somehow i solved the issue by seting focus for textFiled after refreshing of row. thanks for help rahul